# Change existing DIV from a CLASS to an ID

Tags: javascript, html, class

Is this possible? Or is there a way to tack on and ID to an existing div?

This is my code. I can't get the code to work using classes, but I found when I used `getElementById` and changed the div to an ID, that it did. But I have a ton of already posted stuff so it would take forever to go through all those posts and change it manually to an ID.

Can I incorperate JQuery in this and still have it work? I tried that with something I stumbled across but it didn't work so I removed it. I don't remember what it is now though. :S

```
<div id="imdb" class="imdb">tt2382396</div>

<script>
    function imdbdiv() {
        var imdbmain = "http://www.imdb.com/title/";
        var end = "/#overview-top";
        var idnum = document.getElementsByClassName("imdb");
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
        var done = "<a href='" + imdbmain + idnum + end + "'>IMDB</a>";
        newdiv.innerHTML = done;

        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
    window.onload = imdbdiv();
</script>
```

Can anyone help. I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5R27/8/)

Comment: Looks like XY problem; you're looking for the wrong solution. If it's going to take you forever to change classes to ids, then ask about how to fix your class problem. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, are you looping?

Comment: There is no `jQuery` in that code. Why are you tagging it?

Comment: There is an *s* in `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: var idnum = document.getElementsByClassName("imdb")[0];?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("imdb")[0]` (since it returns an array of objects). Also, you're concatenating strings with objects (`imdbmain + idnum`).

Comment: `window.onload = imdbdiv();` <-- wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was, you were appending the collection returned by document.getElementsByClassName instead of looping through the elements in the collection. You can verify this by looking at the `href` property of the link in your jsFiddle. You must loop through the values, then access the data in their innerHTML property.

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of all elements matching a certain CSS selector, in your case `.imdb`. This is more flexible, in case you want to select elements with more than one class. I've pasted the code from the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5R27/15/) below.

```
function imdbdiv() {
    var imdbMain = "http://www.imdb.com/title/",
        end = "/#overview-top",
        imdbValueDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.imdb'),
        length = imdbValueDivs.length,
        // Iterator values
        i,
        newDiv,
        newLink;

    // Loop over all of your link value containers
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Create the container
        newDiv = document.createElement('div');

        // Create the new link
        newLink = document.createElement('a');
        newLink.href = imdbMain + imdbValueDivs[i].innerHTML + end;
        newLink.innerHTML = "My favorite film";

        // Add the link to the container,
        // and add the container to the body
        newDiv.appendChild(newLink);
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}
window.onload = imdbdiv();
```

Comment: Worked even better for my purposes. Thanks. :)

Comment: Only problem is the div is not generated in the place where I put the script and I need it in a particular position within a specified div.

Comment: In that case, replace the `document.body.appendChild` line with `document.querySelector('#mySpecifiedDiv').appendChild`. You can replace `#mySpecifiedDiv` with the correct selector for the container you want.
[Take a look at the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5R27/16/)

Comment: Note that `document.querySelector` returns one element you can access directly, and `document.querySelectorAll` returns a list of HTML elements that you must iterate over to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many such divs on your page, then it could be like this:

```
<div class="imdb">tt2382396</div>
<div class="imdb">tt2382396</div>
<div class="imdb">tt2382396</div>

<script>
    function imdbdiv() {
        var imdbmain = "http://www.imdb.com/title/";
        var end = "/#overview-top";
        var idnums = document.getElementsByClassName("imdb");
        for (var i =0; i < idnums.length; i++) {
            var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
            var done = "<a href='" + imdbmain + idnums[i].innerText + end + "'>IMDB</a>";
            newdiv.innerHTML = done;
            document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        }            
    }
    window.onload = imdbdiv();
</script>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5R27/13/)

**UPDATE:**

The following string was incorrect:

```
window.onload = imdbdiv;
```

Comment: There's only one instance of the class on the page. But this worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your question is a little bit unclear.

The way I understood your question is that you have a whole bunch of div elements with class attribute and what you want is to simply copy the class value to the id attribute of the div elements.

If that's correct then try something like this with jquery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".imdb").each(function(imdbDiv){
          var classValue = imdbDiv.attr("class");
          imdbDiv.attr("id", classValue);
     });

});

</script>
```